# Point to local dependency from remote base image when building Go program Docker image

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, local

Please note that I am new to Golang and Docker development. I have already asked this elsewhere and tried to read the documentation but can't find any solution.

## The problem and code

I have two repos `/home/experience/keep-ecdsa` and `/home/experience/keep-core` which I forked from [this project](https://github.com/keep-network) and cloned locally.

I'm trying to build a docker image for `keep-ecdsa` locally. Here is a link to my [forked repo](https://github.com/jeremyid/keep-ecdsa).

There are some `keep-core` dependencies and I want to point to my local `keep-core` repo.  As such, I changed my `go.mod` to:

```golang
module github.com/keep-network/keep-ecdsa
go 1.13
replace (
    //unrelated stuff...
    github.com/keep-network/keep-core => /home/experience/keep-core
)
require (
    //unrelated stuff...
    github.com/keep-network/keep-core v1.1.3
)
```

The DOCKERFILE starts as follow [(click here to see the full file)](https://github.com/jeremyid/keep-ecdsa/blob/master/Dockerfile) :

```
FROM golang:1.13.8-alpine3.10 AS runtime

ENV APP_NAME=keep-ecdsa \
    BIN_PATH=/usr/local/bin

FROM runtime AS gobuild

ENV GOPATH=/go \
    GOBIN=/go/bin \
    APP_NAME=keep-ecdsa \
    APP_DIR=/go/src/github.com/keep-network/keep-ecdsa \
    BIN_PATH=/usr/local/bin \
    # GO111MODULE required to support go modules
    GO111MODULE=on
    //rest of the linked DOCKERFILE
```

When running `docker build .`, I get the error below which occurs at the `RUN go mod download` step of the `DOCKERFILE`.

```
Step 13/27 : RUN go mod download
--> Running in 88839fc42d4e
go: github.com/keep-network/keep-core@v1.1.3: parsing /home/experience/keep-core/go.mod: open /home/experience/keep-core/go.mod: no such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c go mod download' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

## What I have attempted and a lead

### I have tried to:

- Change my `GOPATH` in the DOCKERFILE to various absolute local fs paths
- Make my `APPDIR`in the DOCKERFILE point to my absolute local path `/home/experience/keep-ecdsa`
- Change the path in the `replace ( )` statement of the `go.mod` to various paths (absolute local, relative to `GOPATH`, etc

### Someone gave me this lead:

> you are inside a `golang:1.13.8-alpine3.10` base image
>   so there is no `/home/experience/keep-core` inside there
>   since that is only on your local fs

But I still have no idea how to achieve wat I want. Perhaps replace the `FROM ... AS runtine` statement in the DOCKERFILE by some local base image? But how do I find such relevant base image, and won't it change the rest of the DOCKERFILE instructions?

Keep in mind that I'm going to do local changes to the `keep-core`dependencies and will need to test them, so a solution that would consist in `replace (github.com/mygithubprofile/keep-core)` is not satisfactory.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't post images that have text. It's hard to read. Copy the error and paste it in

Comment: @FananDala Fixing this now, sorry

Comment: Sorry @FananDala we edited at the same time and becauseof that it automatically rejected your edit when I clicked "Save Edit". Thanks for pointing this out though.

Comment: Can you include the full Docket File? I would like to see what other Docker instructions are run before `RUN go mod download`

Comment: Sure thing @FananDala, here is a link to the full docker file: https://github.com/jeremyid/keep-ecdsa/blob/master/Dockerfile

I will try to make it clearer in the question that I'm linking to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you are inside a golang:1.13.8-alpine3.10 base image so there is no /home/experience/keep-core inside there since that is only on your local fs

From what I can see in the file, you have not copied the `/home/experience/keep-core` directory on your machine to your docker image so it is throwing up the error as that directory does not exist yet.

Docker cannot follow links outside the directory of the current context so if you do not want to edit `replace (github.com/mygithubprofile/keep-core)` you can move your DockerFile to `/home/experience/` and use the `COPY` command to copy `keep-core` folder from your local machine to the docker image.

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/experience/keep-core
COPY ./keep-core /home/experience/keep-core
```

However, if you want the DockerFile to remain in `/home/experience/keep-ecdsa` you could move the `keep-core` folder into the `keep-ecdsa` folder and ignore it in `.gitignore` file. Then update

```golang
replace (
    //unrelated stuff...
    github.com/keep-network/keep-core => /home/experience/keep-core
)
```

TO

```
replace (
    //unrelated stuff...
    github.com/keep-network/keep-core => /home/experience/keep-ecdsa/keep-core
)
```

Comment: I move the dockerfile to /home/experience and added these instructions right after line 37 of the dockerfile, it now throws another error ``COPY go.mod $APP_DIR/ COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tomp/docker-builder763642686/go.mod: no such file or directory``. The solution to move ``keep-core`` to ``keep-ecdsa`` is not nice because then I won't be able to compare my changes with the ``keep-core`` master branch and commit there

Comment: @Experience111 update the copy command to be `COPY keep-ecdsa/go.mod $APP_DIR/`
Basically update your copy commands to now be relative to `/home/experience`

Comment: Looks like this is now compiling without error. I will wait for the end of compilation, test some changes in ``keep-core``to see if they reflect in my local Docker image, and report back.

Comment: I added ``keep-ecdsa`` to all the COPY statements and it is now working. I was able to test some local changes which properly reflect in my Docker image. Thank you very much for your help !